# Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration, And HTTP response: 403 Forbidden

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I am using Firebase Remote Config and Firebase Cloud Messaging then getting the following error.

- Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.
- FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to get FIS auth token

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjSCK.png)

Comment: You need to check firebase console and your added app. Is everything needed is settled up there or not.

Comment: Already solved, after I created a new google map credential. And I updated firebase in my andorid studio project